# Splitting an array into two subarrays with minimal absolute difference

Tags: ruby, algorithm

For example, consider array A:

```
[3, 1, 2, 4, 3]
```

I can split this array in four places:

```
    P = 1, difference = |3 − 10| = 7
    P = 2, difference = |4 − 9| = 5
    P = 3, difference = |6 − 7| = 1
    P = 4, difference = |10 − 3| = 7
```

The minimal difference is 1.

Each element of array is an integer within the range [−1,000..1,000].

Below is the code I wrote. My code is correct for this exercise, and is correct for the given input but incorrect in some other cases. I do not understand why.

```
def minimaldifference(a)
    sumArr = []
    sumArr = sumfromstarting(a)
    sum  = sumArr.last 
    sumRev = sumFromReverse(a, sum)

    size  = sumArr.size-2
    min = 0
    v = 0
    for i in 0..size
        if(i==0)
            min = (sumArr[i] - sumRev[i]).abs
        else
            v = (sumArr[i] - sumRev[i]).abs
            if( v < min)
                min = v
            end
        end
    end
    min
end

def sumfromstarting(a)
    sumArr = []
    sum = 0
    a.each do |i|
        sum += i
        sumArr.push(sum)
    end
    sumArr
end

def sumFromReverse(a, sum)
    sumArr = []
    rsum = 0
    a.each do |i|
        rsum += i
        sumArr.push(sum - i)
    end
    sumArr
end
a = [3, 1, 2, 4, 3]
puts minimaldifference(a)
```

Comment: Stylistically, you need to use camel_case for method and variable names. `sumFromReverse` should be `sum_from_reverse` for instance. `sumArr` should be `sum_arr`. That's the Ruby way, and being consistent with that is important if you ever want to write code being used by the community or in a development team. Also `sumfromstarting` should have underscores separating the words. That helps readability. Plus be consistent in your naming and capitalization styles.

Comment: Do not understand why this was voted down. Good question, show an attempt at solving the problem. +1

Comment: Don't know why. Perhaps its because it's missing adequate input and output samples, especially an input that shows what triggers the error? Making us search for it is a waste of our time.

Comment: Algorithmic efficiency depends in part on whether all elements of the array are guaranteed to be non-negative.  Are they necessarily non-negative?

Comment: For which inputs is your algorithm incorrect? What is the expected output, what is the actual output?

Comment: @theTinMan Got you .. I was juggling with languages, recently  used java. Thanks allot for the suggestion

Comment: There was just a silly mistake, I got it. I had to subtract rsum in the below statement
`sumArr.push(sum - i)`

Comment: I will post an answer if you answer my question in the affirmative, but any answer would be appreciated.

Comment: My downvote is for changing the question with your last edit. If I could downvote again for a misleading comment, I would.

Answer (score 0):

This solution requires that all elements of the array be non-negative, which I understand is the case.

Consider

```
a = [4,1,3,1,2,4,3,1,5]
```

The possible partitions of this array are as follows:

```
      Partition                 Totals          Diff  Abs Diff
[4], [1,3,1,2,4,3,1,5]                [4,  20]  
[4,1], [3,1,2,4,3,1,5]  [4+1, 20-1] =>[5,  19]   -14     14
[4,1,3], [1,2,4,3,1,5]  [5+3, 19-3] =>[8,  16]    -8      8 
[4,1,3,1], [2,4,3,1,5]  [8+1, 16-1] =>[9,  15]    -6      6
[4,1,3,1,2], [4,3,1,5]  [9+2, 15-2] =>[11, 13]    -2      2
[4,1,3,1,2,4], [3,1,5]  [11+4, 13-4]=>[15,  9]     6      6 
[4,1,3,1,2,4,3], [1,5]  [15+3, 9-3] =>[18,  6]    12     12 
[4,1,3,1,2,4,3,1], [5]  [18+1, 6-1] =>[19,  5]    14     14
```

In each row of this table "Diff" equals the difference between the totals for the two sets. Because all elements of `a` are non-negative, these values are monotonically non-decreasing. The absolute differences are therefore non-increasing then non-decreasing. It follows that to obtain the minimum absolute difference of totals we simply step through this array,  stopping when the absolute difference would increase if the next element were moved from the "right" array to the "left" array.

We can implement this in code as follows.

```
def minimize_difference(arr)
  raise ArgumentError, "array must contain at least two elements" if arr.size < 2 
  left, *right = arr
  last = left - right.reduce(:+)
  left = [left]
  while right.any?
    test = last + 2*right.first
    break if test.abs > last.abs
    last = test
    left << right.shift
  end
  [left, right, last.abs]
end  

minimize_difference [3, 1, 2, 4, 3]
  #=> [[3, 1, 2], [4, 3], 1]
```

Comment: Please see the qs once more .. the numbers can be negative

Comment: I asked you if the elements of the array were guaranteed to be non-negative. You did not answer. I see now that you edited your question the *following day* to indicate that array elements could be negative. I obviously did not see that edit because later I said I would provide an answer if you answered my question in the affirmative. You answered, "yes", so I wasted my time preparing an answer.